# Get xml attribute

Tags: php, jquery, xml, wordpress

I am working on a plugin with multiple widget each fill with a different XML file. My XML files represent all my categories ( I have 7 categories ) and have multiple items in them.

XML example :

```
<channel>
  <category> This XML category </category>
  <item>
    <title> Item title 1 </title>
    <description> This is the first item description. </description>
  </item>  
  <item>
    <title> Item title 2 </title>
    <description> This is the second item description. </description>
  </item>    
</channel>
```

What my plugin do is it take a XML file and use it to fill a widget with its items. Each item have a button link to it and when I click it it call a jQuery function.

PHP :

```
foreach ( $channel->channel->item as $item )  {
  echo "<div class='xppArticle'>";
    echo "<h2>" . $item->title . "</h2>";
    if ( preg_match( '/p$/', $this->set_paragraph_length_display( $item->description, 400 ) ) || preg_match( '/\\/$/', $this->set_paragraph_length_display( $item->description, 400 ) ) ) {
      echo "<p>". html_entity_decode( $this->set_paragraph_length_display( $item->description, 375 ) ) . "(...)" ."</p>";
    }
    else {
      echo "<p>". html_entity_decode( $this->set_paragraph_length_display( $item->description, 400 ) ) . "(...)" . "</p>";
    }

    global $wpdb;
    $query = $wpdb->prepare ( 'SELECT ID FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE post_title = %s', $item->title );
    $cID = $wpdb->get_var( $query ) ;

    if ( ! empty( $cID ) ) {
      echo "<input type='button' class='putPending button-primary' value='Already publish' disabled='disabled' />";
    }
    else {
      echo "<input type='button' class='putPending button-primary' value='Edit' />";
    }
    echo "<hr />";
  echo "</div>";
}
```

jQuery :

```
jQuery( '.putPending' ).live( 'click', function( ) {
  var title = jQuery( this ).siblings( "h2" ).text( ); 

  jQuery.ajax( {
    url: ajaxurl,
    datatype: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    data:
    {
      action: 'ajax_fill_post',
      title: title,
    },
    success: function( data )
    {
      var result = JSON.parse( data );
      window.location.href = result.url;
    }            
  });        
});
```

My jQuery return **title** to my **post_item_function** ( I won't show it because it's 100+ line ) . A foreach take **$current_category** and search for a item' title correspondent to $title. Without **$current_category** I can't do it in a single foreach and it will add like 250-300 more line to my plugin.

Comment: Can you please clarify this -> `from my jQuery without having to show it like my title`.

Comment: The only way I currently could get my category is by showing it in my widget like my title ( <h2>title</h2> ). But I don't want to because it will show with every item and I have like 15 items by xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of the loop that you have built, you could simply iterate the `category` XML tag and then create hidden input for it.

```
foreach ( $channel->channel->category as $idx => $category);
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="category" class="category" data-categoryIndex="'.$idx.'"  value="'.$category.'"/>';
endforeach;
```

Then you can access it as so:

```
$('.category[data-categoryIndex="'+1/2/3/etc+'"]').val();
```

Which would give you the category based on a `data-categoryIndex="1/2/3/etc"` which has been assigned by our `$idx` variable in our `foreach` loop.

If you only ever have one category, then it's simple:

```
$('.category').val();
```